# Wrong output when I run code in Eclipse Indigo CDT

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse Indigo CDT and just running simple code which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num;
    printf("enter no\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("no is %d\n",num);

}
```

Opuput:

```
55
enter no
no is 55
```

But when I run this code it won't print `enter no`. Instead of that it waits to enter the number. After pressing some number it is printing `enter no`. What could be the reason?

Comment: Please, format your code.

Comment: What file are you including?

Comment: try `printf("enter no\n");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: First: It's 'int main()', not 'void main()'. Second: I tried to replicate your behaviour in Eclipse Kepler CDT but it works well for me. If you used custom settings to compile or execute please tell us.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY If the buffering mode for stdout is _IOLBF (the default) it should flush the buffer automatically when a '\n' is written, so doing fflush should be unnecessary.

Comment: thank you BLUEPIXY...it worked...! So every time do i need to add fflush(stdout),when i use printf()???

Comment: @ Mabus i tried with in main() and used return 0;..till its not working.. but the same code works fine in eclipse juno(same system).

Comment: Is the code working well if compiled with Eclipse but executed outside? Because I bet it's a Eclipse problem, not a code one.

Comment: Your code is likely to be executed outside Eclipse, so if it works well outside, you have no problem. You could try, however, to use setvbuf with stdout and mode _IOLBF and see if it works in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on the flush scheme of standard out.

Traditionally, stdout is line buffered when connected to a terminal and page buffered when it's not connected to a terminal.

Apparantly, when you run your program in eclipse, standard out is page buffered.

You can overcome this by flushing stdout:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num;
    printf("enter no\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("no is %d\n",num);

}
```

It is good practice to flush a file handle whenever you expect the recipient of the information to respond. That way you can be sure that the recipient gets everything you have written regardless of the buffering of the file handle.

Comment: I think it's better to use setvbuf to automatically flush when a '\n' is printed.